# How is a public key used that is generated when a Microsoft Edge extension is submitted on Partner Center?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

While uploading my extension to Microsoft Partner Centre, I have got a "Public key" for my extension along with CRX ID and Store ID.
I could not find any documentation on the use of this Public key in Microsoft Edge Add-ons. Can I know the use of this key?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find about **public key** in [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/enterprise/auto-update#updated-manifest) is this:

> The extension ID is generated based on a hash of the public key.

So I think the use of the public key is to generate extension ID.